# confused with the FileSystemCounters about Job completion History in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

In the Job completion History of hadoop, I am confused with some FileSystemCounters.

1. What's the difference about FILE_BYTES_READ and HDFS_BYTES_READ.
2. Why does HDFS_BYTES_READ have a different value with Map input bytes?
3. What's the difference between Spilled Records and Reduce output records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an explanation
a) FILE_BYTES_READ - 
         Is computed when the input to the Mapper is from a local file. Usually 0 but when  mapper emits files as intermediate output , there is a merge sort that happens to consolidate the files. The FILE_BYTES_READ in mapper is that.

b) HDFS_BYTES_READ - 
        For mapper, it is the map input bytes from HDFS including meta data about splits.
        For reducer, it is usually 0.

c) Map Input bytes -
        Exact number of input bytes that the mapper read. Usually , the input bytes would be marginally less than HDFS_BYTES_READ .

d) Spilled Records - 
        For mapper and reducer, its the number of records that spilled over to disk during the job execution

e)  Reduce Output records - 
     The final number of records emitted from reducers.

Comment: I am still confused with FILE_BYTES_READ, You mean it always related with Mapper instead of reducer?  @Magham Ravi